# Javascript attach an onclick event to all link with href variable

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am attempting to add an onclick function to all my links with the class of "external-link".  So I've successfully done it and did a test where anytime I click on one it alerts "it works" but how do return the href of that link into the function?  I'd like to throw in that variable where it says "http://www.example.com".  I tried elements[i].href but it says it's undefined.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('external-link');
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function () {
      trackOutboundLink(‘http://www.example.com’); return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of your onclick callback will be the link that's clicked so you can simply use 'this.href'

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('external-link');
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function () {
      trackOutboundLink(this.href); return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using jQuery for this?
It helps keep a straightforward and clean code, compatible to most browsers, and frees you from dealing with complex object trees.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.external-link").click(function(){
    alert("You clicked an external link to: " + $(this).attr("href"));
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="external-link" href="http://www.example1.com">Example 1</a><br>
<a class="external-link" href="http://www.example2.com">Example 2</a><br>
<a class="internal-link" href="http://www.example3.com">Example 3</a> - <i>no alert</i>
</body>
</html>
```

Resources:

- [jQuery Tutorial 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/)
- [jQuery Tutorial 2](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)